# Angular-JS: Multiple error messages on single field based on numeric or alphanumeric patterns

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a REFERENCE_NUMBER field that needs different validations for different conditions. e.g. when payment type is "A" then the REFERENCE_NUMBER field must be alphanumeric with certain length. When payment type if "B" then the REFERENCE_NUMBER field must be Numeric with different length. I am validating usng regex pattern (ng-pattern). In case "A" I need ng-message for pattern to display "Must enter only alphanumeric value" and in case "B" I need a message that "Must enter only numeric value". How can I achieve this with single field to identify whether the pattern is Numeric or Alphanumeric?

In my controller I have created an object to select pattern based on payment mode -

```
var refnumpattern = {
    1: {"maxlength":"100","ngpattern":""}, //cash
    2: {"maxlength":"100","ngpattern":"" } , //credit card
    3: {"maxlength":"6", "ngpattern":"^[0-9]+$"},//DD
    4: {"maxlength":"100","ngpattern":""},//Debit card
    5: {"maxlength":"100" , "ngpattern":""},//netbanking
    6: {"maxlength":"6", "ngpattern":"^[0-9]+$"},//Cheque
    7: {"maxlength":"100","ngpattern":""},//COD
    8: {"maxlength":"11", "ngpattern":"^[0-9]+$"}, //merchant
};

$scope.referenceNumberPattern = refnumpattern[$scope.paymentMode.ID];
```

In Html I am using the referenceNumberPattern object to set the maxlength and pattern -

```
<input id="txtReference" name="txtReference" type="text" ng-model="referenceNumber" ng-pattern="{{referenceNumberPattern.ngpattern}}" ng-maxlength="{{referenceNumberPattern.maxlength}}" />

<div ng-messages="aForm.txtReference.$error" ng-show="aForm.txtReference.$dirty && aForm.txtReference.$invalid" class=" error-message">
    <div ng-message="pattern">Please enter alphabets, numbers and spaces</div> <!-- Here I need to display numeric or alphanumeric message based on the pattern -->
    <div ng-message="maxlength">Reference Number can be of {{referenceNumberPattern.maxlength}} length only</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is first of all check the type. and decide what regex expression and error message you are going to use.

```
if($scope.type == 'A')
{
     $scope.pattern= 'your expression';
     $scope.errorMessage = 'your error message';
     $scope.maxLenght = 10;
}
else if($scope.type == 'B')
{
     $scope.pattern= 'your expression';
     $scope.errorMessage = 'your error message';
     $scope.maxLenght = 20;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This looks ok to me. But is there any other way? Can i have two ng-message for "pattern" attribute one displayed for numeric and other for  alphanumeric for a single field? as below -    
                                 `<div ng-message="pattern" ng-show="!referenceNumberPattern.isNumeric">Please enter alphabets, numbers and spaces</div>
                                    <div ng-message="pattern" ng-show="referenceNumberPattern.isNumeric">Enter numbers only</div>
                                    </div>`

Comment: @UmeshK I guess yes. If I understand your problem correctly, then you will need to refer to two different variables like $scope.numericPattern and $scope.alphaNumericPattern.